# Print physical plan of query Hive on Spark

Tags: hive

I'm using hive 2.3.7 and spark-2.0.0 as the execution engine.
I was wondering how can i print the physical plan , to see which join algorithm for example caclcite choose to execute on a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explain`.

In Pyspark:

```
df = df1.join(df2, 'id')
df.explain()
```

In Spark SQL / Hive QL:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

See more details at

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-explain.html

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain

Comment: Thank you for your answer but im afraid that is spark on hive and not hive on spark. I'm talking about this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

Comment: Spark SQL should also work on HiveQL, try if it works